# `{Protected, ReadProtected}` System symbols give "Set::write: "Tag * in *[v_] is Protected" on first try

Tags: warning-messages, kernel-startup, attributes

Run `Quit`, then

```
Unprotect@AbelianGroup;
AbelianGroup[v_] = 0;
Protect@AbelianGroup;
```

where instead of `AbelianGroup` you can pick any of `` Select[Names["System`*"], 
 Attributes@# == {Protected, ReadProtected} &] ``.

You get `Set::write: Tag AbelianGroup in AbelianGroup[v_] is Protected. >>`.
However, if you run the same thing again, there's no message. There's also no message if you do `Quit` again and run the following code mentioning the symbol once before unprotecting:

```
AbelianGroup;
Unprotect@AbelianGroup;
AbelianGroup[v_] = 0;
Protect@AbelianGroup;
```

Is this a bug?

I have

```
$Version
"10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"
```

Comment: The behavior would be due to the fact that the symbols are stubs up until they are invoked/touched (this apparently is the case with the newer functions) and an internal dump file is brought up to load the required definitions, which usually include a `Protect[]` somewhere in there. Try `Unprotect@AbelianGroup; AbelianGroup; Attributes[AbelianGroup]`, for instance.

Comment: So does this count as an answer? How do you know this?

Comment: Somebody might write a more authoritative answer; my notes are something that turned up from spelunking experience. In the current case, the internals are associated with the context ``GroupTheory`PermutationGroups`​``.