# `$ContextPath` different on first run

Tags: contexts, kernel-startup

When I run `Quit`, then the first time after that I evaluate `$ContextPath` I get `` {"IconizeLoader`", "StreamingLoader`", "CloudObjectLoader`", "PacletManager`", "System`", "Global`"} ``. But running `$ContextPath` once more after that, it's `` {"CloudObject`", "Security`", "System`"} ``. Every later time I get this.

Can anyone reproduce this? Why is that? Shouldn't `` Global` `` be part of `$ContextPath`?

Maybe this is related to symbols being loaded lazily, as in 
[`{Protected, ReadProtected}` System symbols give "Set::write: "Tag * in *[v_] is Protected" on first try](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119814/protected-readprotected-system-symbols-give-setwrite-tag-in-v-is)
?

Comment: On Mathematica 10.4, I get `{"CloudObjectLoader`", "StreamingLoader`", "IconizeLoader`", "PacletManager`", "System`", "Global`"}` each time - the same as your first run, but a slight different.

Comment: Can you post your precise version (three-part: x.y.z)?

Comment: Yes, ``Global` `` must be in the `$ContextPath`, not only in `$Context`.  Other things that may be important: (1) What's in your init.m?  (2) Does it do it if you run the kernel with no front end?  (3)  Is your suggestions bar on or off?

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for pointing out the Suggestions bar, that must have been it. But it seems fixed in 10.4 (working fine even with the sb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a problem with the Suggestions Bar

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75284/6804

When I disable it, I get the same context path consistently. This is version 10.2.

The problem does not appear in 10.4, suggestions bar on or off...